# Data is not being inserted in database

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing an ASP.Net MVC application, and am running into a bizzare issue when trying to update data in my database . I'm still new when it comes to hit submit button then it shows no error but data is also not being inserted

Basically, when I try to insert a data linking content areas to form, the update sometimes works, sometimes doesn't. It was working fine but i don't know why it stop working as i inserted jquery validation in it , I query the database directly from the MVC application just to make sure that the expected change was in fact made  In every case, the query returns what I hope to see. But then when I query the table , I see that the change only sometimes goes through.

How is it that a direct query to a table from my MVC application is showing that an update went through, while Is there a silent rollback or something? This is maddening and any help would be much appreciated.

I am also using kendo grid but when i update kendo grid database is updated but when i want to insert data through form.
Here is my Controller

### Controller

```
     // GET: PersonalDetails/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: PersonalDetails/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific
properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include =
"AutoId,FirstName,LastName,Age,Active")] PersonalDetail personalDetail)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.PersonalDetails.Add(personalDetail);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(personalDetail);
        }
```

### CREATE.CSHTML VIEW

```
    @model WebApplication1.Models.PersonalDetail

   @{
       ViewBag.Title = "Create";
   }

   <h2>Create</h2>

   @using (Html.BeginForm())
   {
       <text>

       First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" />
       Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" />
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
       </text>
   }

   @using (Html.BeginForm())
   {
       @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

       <div class="form-horizontal">
           <h4>PersonalDetail</h4>
           <hr />
           @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
           <div class="form-group">
               @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class =
"control-label col-md-2" })
               <div class="col-md-10">
                   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new
{ @class = "form-control" } })
                   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new {
@class = "text-danger" })
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
               @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class =
"control-label col-md-2" })
               <div class="col-md-10">
                   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new
{ @class = "form-control" } })
                   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class
= "text-danger" })
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
               @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Age, htmlAttributes: new { @class =
"control-label col-md-2" })
               <div class="col-md-10">
                   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Age, new { htmlAttributes = new {
@class = "form-control" } })
                   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Age, "", new { @class =
"text-danger" })
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
               @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Active, htmlAttributes: new { @class =
"control-label col-md-2" })
               <div class="col-md-10">
                   <div class="checkbox">
                       @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Active)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Active, "", new {
@class = "text-danger" })
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
               <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                   <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
    @section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Please Help me out

Comment: Why are you using two forms ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this type of issues.
This can be a possible reason.

You are using `PersonalDetail` `model`. Sometimes jquery validation has issues like this for some model properties. For checking which properties are causing issue you just follow these steps.

1. Fill form
2. Hit Submit
3. Go to Html Elements in Inspect
4. Search `input-validation-error`

If this `input-validation error` is found in html then this property has issue.

Comment: I don't think this will solve my problem i tried that